# Python error updating a SQL DB

Tags: python, ms-access, pypyodbc

I have some python code that looks like this

```
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd
home="c:/SQL/"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql4, conn3
for y1 in range(0 , k):
    ARCHIVE_SERNUM = (df['sernum']).iloc[y1]
    KQL=len(KIC53_QUERY_LIST)
    FOUND=False
    for y2 in range(0,KQL):
        if ARCHIVE_SERNUM == KIC53_QUERY_LIST[y2]:
            FOUND=True
            #do something then
            break
    if FOUND == False:
        print(FOUND,ARCHIVE_SERNUM,"This is STIME : ",STIME)
        CTIME=STIME
        cursor = conn3.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            UPDATE ENCOMPASS_DIA
            SET CTIME=%s
            WHERE SERNUM=ARCHIVE_SERNUM
            """, (STIME))
```

Its throwing an error and I cannot figure out what is going on.
In this example both CTIME and STIME are equal to the same 17 character string.

```
File "c:/SQL/ConnectionTest8.py", line 212, in <module>
""", (STIME))

TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the correct Update statement is:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE ENCOMPASS_DIA SET CTIME=? WHERE SERNUM=?""", (SSTIME,ARCHIVE_SERNUM ))
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy enough mistake to make.

```
 cursor.execute("""
        UPDATE ENCOMPASS_DIA
        SET CTIME=%s
        WHERE SERNUM=ARCHIVE_SERNUM
        """, (STIME, ))
```

There should be a trailing `,` after the `STIME` or (STIME) will be interpreted as a list instead of a tuple.

Comment: does the fact I'm using an access DB make a difference? Your solution resulted in this error message:                                       
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in query expression '%s'.")

Comment: Sorry missed the pyodbc tag. Here you have to use `?` instead of `%s`

Comment: Is this sorted out now?

Comment: Sorry, I discovered the error and posted the findings, right after found that that '%s' error, and then forgot to press the acceptance arrow.